# Rank If Array Formula

Tags: excel-formula, array-formulas

I need some help creating a `RankIf` formula for the following situation.

In my table I have the following

```
|UniqueRank|LkUp|
|12        |0   |
|13        |1   |
|5         |0   |
|1         |2   |
```

I'm trying to create a third column that will rank field UniqueRank if field LkUp does not = 0.  As the column title suggests, all values in this column are unique.

I have written the following array formula;

```
=IF(tblPriorityMatrix[LkUp]<>0,RANK.EQ(tblPriorityMatrix[Unique Rank],tblPriorityMatrix[@[Unique Rank]]),0)
```

This returns 0 where the criteria is **not** met, but **#N/A** where it is met.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=IF(tblPriorityMatrix[@LkUp]<>0,SUMPRODUCT((tblPriorityMatrix[UniqueRank]>tblPriorityMatrix[@UniqueRank])*(tblPriorityMatrix[LkUp]<>0))+1,0)
```

To change it to ascending order just change the `>` to `<`:

```
=IF(tblPriorityMatrix[@LkUp]<>0,SUMPRODUCT((tblPriorityMatrix[UniqueRank]<tblPriorityMatrix[@UniqueRank])*(tblPriorityMatrix[LkUp]<>0))+1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply.  This seems to work, but in descending order, how do you change this to ascending?

Comment: Hi Scott, it's obvious when you point it out :)  Many, many thanks for helping, this works a charm!